# How to make the current prompt of R at the top of buffer in ESS just like Control + L in R console

Tags: r, emacs, elisp, ess

I have tried to put the following in `my .emacs` file.

```
(defun clear-shell ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((old-max comint-buffer-maximum-size))
     (setq comint-buffer-maximum-size 0)
     (comint-truncate-buffer)
     (setq comint-buffer-maximum-size old-max))) 
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-x c") 'clear-shell)
```

It worked, but it also remove all the command I have typed before. So it is not what I want. I just want the current prompt > at the top of the buffer and not to delete any command I typed before.

Does anyone know?

Comment: For the record,the `let` part of your code can be rewritten `(let ((comint-buffer-maximum-size 0)) (comint-truncate-buffer))`.

Answer (score 2):

For me `Esc-0 Ctr-l` seems to work.

`Ctrl-h k' output is:

```
C-l runs the command recenter-top-bottom,
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in window.el'.
```

According to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html) from the Emacs manual:

```
Scroll the selected window so the current line is the 
center-most text line; on subsequent consecutive invocations,
make the current line the top line, the bottom line, and so on in
cyclic order. Possibly redisplay the screen too (recenter-top-bottom).
```

Comment: Do you mean Meta-0 Ctrl-l?

Comment: No, in my case it is literally `Esc`. [Edit] But yes, `M-0 Ctrl-l` also works.

Comment: Does not work for me... but maybe for OP. What is bound to that command btw?

Comment: And what is bound to Ctrl-l in your inferior-ess-mode? Btw, I don't think this Esc-0's definition is important, it is the same as M-0 or C-0 for most people (it's just a `digit-argument`).

Comment: `C-l runs the command recenter-top-bottom, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.`

Comment: ``Esc 0 C-l`` is the same for ``M-0 C-l`` or ``C-0 C-l`` or ``C-u 0 C-l``.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get the job done (though I am actually not really sure if this is what you are after):

```
(defun clean-shell ()
 (interactive)

 ; if you call this from your .r script, it will switch to the next window
 (when (eq major-mode 'ess-mode) (other-window 1))   

 (mark-whole-buffer)
 (exchange-point-and-mark)
 (move-beginning-of-line 1)
 (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
 (end-of-line)
)
```

EDIT: Or maybe this?

```
(defun clean-shell ()
 (interactive)
 (when (eq major-mode 'ess-mode) (other-window 1))
 (mark-whole-buffer)
 (exchange-point-and-mark)
 (move-beginning-of-line 0)
 (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
 (end-of-line)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not what I'm after. Maybe I didn't state it clear. When I run the command that you provide, although the prompt is returned to the top of the buffer, I cannot see the command that I typed before I run the command. In other words. The line number of prompt after running clean-shell is one. But I want it the same as that before running clean-shell commend. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly has to be cleaned up?

Comment: When I run this, and I have typed something on the last line, it will still be there after this cleaning up. Or do you want the thing ran before that also to be there? So, the last thing should be there?

Comment: Yes. I want the thing ran before that also to be there.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with <kbd>C-l C-l</kbd>? It works in any buffer.

Comment: It isn't, if you change ``recenter-positions``. And I'm not talking about the fact it does not actually delete anything.